# "Main method not found in class...." but it is there ?? so why the error?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I'm getting the error:

> `Main` method not found in class `Pythag`, please define the main method as:
>
> ```
>    public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

But as you can see in the code below it is there? So why the error? This seems to happen a lot 
to my classes in Eclipse Java EE IDE.

```
public class Pythag {

    // All Java applications have a main() method.
    // This one does a simple Pythagorean calculation.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare fields and initialise values(input).
        int firstNum = 17;
        int secondNum = 6;
        int answer;

        // Do the calculation (process).
        // 
        answer = (firstNum * firstNum) + (secondNum * secondNum);

        // Display the results (output).
        // 
        System.out.println("The square of the hypotenuse is "
                           + "equal to the sum of the squares "
                           + "of the other two sides.");
        System.out.println("For example...");
        System.out.println(answer + " = " + firstNum + " squared + "
                           + secondNum + " squared.");

    }
}
```

Comment: try cleaning & rebuilding

Comment: great idea...will do :-)

Comment: check if you define the class in Pythag.java, compile it like javac Pythag.java and then run java Pythag. It should work as i dont see any issues with your code.

Comment: I have cleaned and it didn't work ....  I feel a bit stuck in Eclipse because it's what we always use at University so I try to stick with same IDE for that reason ...

Comment: It works when I run it in command line but not in Eclipse ?

Comment: You don't have, by any chance, another class Pythag in your workspace? In another project?

Comment: The code runs just fine in my Eclipse. Obviously there is something else, some other detail, that you're overlooking. What steps, exactly, are you taking to run the class? In Package Explorer, does the .java file contain the `Pythag` class with a small green arrow decorator on the C icon?

Comment: I don't think so @laune, all other projects are closed anyway....

Comment: @pbabcdefp Why?  Millions of programmers around the world use Eclipse successfully.  The fact that Catess is doing something wrong (we don't know what) is no reason to learn a completely different IDE.

Comment: Occasionally, I've re-edited (changing nothing), saved, and recompiled and suddenly it worked. But I guess you did that, too?

Comment: Yes @E-Riz that is there ....

Comment: Well I just tried validating the code.... it came up with no warnings or errors and then ran ..... ??? Why does this happen in Eclipse ? I waste hours of my time farting around and then it just starts working ? so annoying ??? Don't get this ?

Comment: @DavidWallace That is a fair point. I guess it wasn't a very helpful suggestion. Comment deleted. :)

Comment: I can reproduce this!

Comment: @laune If you know how to reproduce this, it would be really good if you could post an answer; so that anyone who encounters this problem in the future knows how to deal with it.

Comment: Create a project helloworld. It contains a package "hello". In it, create class HelloWorld with main, as usual, compile, run, ok. Now, use an operating system command to move the Jave file from helloworld/src/hello/HelloWorld.java to helloworld/src/HelloWorld.java. Refresh doesn't change, and trying to run HelloWorld results in the error message as reported.

Comment: Before anybody else tries this, let me repeat it, please.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Sorry. I'm sure I saw this error message after messing around with the file, moving it into the parent (src) directory. - Changing the file system is one way of fooling Eclipse; of course, refresh needs to be done in the right place.

Comment: @E-Riz we haven't even determined that that's what Catess did.  That was laune's idea - and it may or may not have been what led to Catess' error.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried VALIDATING my code and it then ran fine? Not sure what the problem was or why it wouldn't work but validating the code seemed to sort it out so, there we go?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this class is defined in a file called Pythag.java it can be compiled and run like this:

```
$ javac Pythag.java 
$ java Pythag
The square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.
For example...
325 = 17 squared + 6 squared.
```

This output was generated by copying your code sample directly into a file called Pythag.java with no edits.

Comment: I have done this in command line, as i had en error I couldn't see there at first which Eclipse helped me find.... just annoyed it won't run in Eclipse now.